# I am trying to export HTML table to Excel, but no excel generated

Tags: c#, jquery, html, excel

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExportTableToExcel(string htmlTable)
    {
        EFWPResponse Result = new EFWPResponse() { RequestStatus = false };

        try
        {
             Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=FileEName.xls");
             Response.Charset = "";
             Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
             Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
             //this.EnableViewState = false;
             Response.Write(htmlTable);
             Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", ex);
        }
        return Json(Result);
    }
```

// Code executes successfuly but no excel file opens.
//Can any body please what to do to generate Excel file open in C# with jquery.

Comment: If you take out the content disposition and content type headers, do you see the table in the browser?  If so,then with the headers in-place use Fiddler or Charles to view the data sent over the wire and see if the headers were sent and if there were any duplicates.  Also check different browsers.

Comment: Are you trying to export the xls file via an ajax call?